# MSBuild MSB4096 error with Azure SDK 2.9.1

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

So here is the issue:  I have recently upgraded my development computer to Windows 10 (from 8.1), then my Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (from 2013).  I also upgraded to Azure SDK 2.9.1 (from 2.4).  I reloaded the extensions and updates and was easily saddled to build and run the solution locally.

However, it is a different story when it comes to publish on Azure.  I have a script to run the MSbuild command, which used to work like a charm.   But it now ends with the following error:

> "C:\development\Organization\Development\Project42.sln" (default target) (1) ->
>   "C:\development\Organization\Development\Project42.Azure\Project42.Azure.ccproj.metaproj"
>   (default target) (12) ->
>   "C:\development\Organization\Development\Project42.Azure\Project42.Azure.ccproj"
>   (default target) (13) -> (PrepareRoleItems target) ->   C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure
>   Tools\2.9\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(1378,5): error MSB4096: The
>   item
>   "C:\development\Organization\Development\Project42.Admin.Web\Project42.Admin.Web.csproj"
>   in item list "ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration" does not define a
>   value for metadata "Name".  In order to use this metadata, either
>   qualify it by specifying %(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration.Name), or
>   ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.
>   [C:\development\Organization\Development\Project42.Azure\Project42.Azure.ccproj]

I suppose that this problem is coming from the upgrade, and I can’t put my finger on it.  Any suggestion to help troubleshooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have a solution but it requires to change the following configuration file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.9\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets

To write

`<ProjectName>%(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration.Name)</ProjectName>`

instead of

`<ProjectName>%(Name)</ProjectName>`

in two locations: ligne 1380 and 1395.  It did the trick!